# The term 'Unblock-File' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, sc ript file, or operable program

Tags: flutter, command-prompt

**I am using windows 7 and command prompt for coding. i have a problem related to flutter .
When i type "flutter doctor" in cmd it show me this error.**

[image]

Can anyone help me? How to solve this problem?

Comment: No screenshots of text please.  Paste the text enclosed with ``` on a line by itself both before and after the text.

Comment: But the quick answer looks like "upgrade powershell"